# AIP RMS sdk 2.1: User not authenticated

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get templates from my RMS through the MSDN sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/developing-your-application
It uses the C# ManagedAPI to interact with the RMS.

Authentication through PowerShell succeeded, but it is failed throught the console application:

[image]

[image: Exception]

I do all from the sample to get TenantId, AddPrincipalId and Key, but requesting RMS failed.

Maybe someone knows what I missed?

Comment: Could you provide some more details about the `ipcConnectionInfo` you are using?

It is probably constructed like this:

`IpcConnectionInfo ipcConnectionInfo = ConnectionInfoToIpcConnectionInfo(connectionInfo);`

What is connectionInfo in this case? The error you are getting seems not to be directly Azure AD/RMS related, but rather an auth issue to e.g. an intranet location.

Comment: Oh, I see:) But could you please help me? What exactly I should specify in the connection info? P.S. it is null for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So missed that if you are outside North America you should specify ipcConnectionInfo for connecting to the service.

```
   static Uri IntranetURL = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LicensingIntranetDistributionPointUrl"]);
   static Uri ExtranetURL = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LicensingExtranetDistributionPointUrl"]);
   static  ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ExtranetURL, IntranetURL);
```